# Scala method clone in class Object cannot be accessed in T Access to protected method clone not permitted because

Tags: scala, clone

I've got troubles with cloning in Scala. Is this possible to clone an object of an arbitrary type T? Something like this:

```
import collection.immutable.Stack

object Tester extends App {
  trait Grand[T <: Cloneable] {
    val stack = Stack[T]()
    val h: T

    def snapshot() {
      stack push h.clone().asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }
}
```

however it throws:
**scala: method clone in class Object cannot be accessed in T

 Access to protected method clone not permitted because
 prefix type T does not conform to
 trait Grand in object Tester where the access take place**

What goes wrong there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was advised on this question. In such a situation the best approach is to use structural typing:

```
trait Grand[T <: {def cloneObject: T}]
```

so that the user code might be the following:

```
case class Person(name: String) {
  def cloneObject = copy()
}

object Roll extends App with Grand[Person] {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

clone() is from java.lang.Object not from java.lang.Cloneable. Cloneable is just a tagging-interface.

What you are trying probably does not work because implementing Cloneable does not force the implementor to override the protected Object.clone() with a public one.

see
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()
and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

ln conclusion:
No it is not possible to clone an object of an arbitrary type T1.
You could however clone any object of type T2 where T2 is bound by a type with a public override of clone().
Your example fails because Object.clone() is protected, i.e. can only be called from within a subclass.

Comment: Yes, but I tried **T <: AnyRef** and **T <: java.lang.Object**. Neither of them works

Comment: For your call to clone() to work, T needs to be bound by a type with a public override of clone().