# Call Java method from Scala named "clone"

Tags: java, api, scala, clone

I want to call a Java method with the following API from Scala:

```
// Java API
public interface JavaAPI {
  JustSomeAPISpecificType clone();
}

// Scala code in class a.b.c.D
val api: JavaAPI = factory.getAPI
val result: JustSomeAPISpecificType = api.clone
```

However, this does not work, as the Scala compiler (2.10) thinks I want to call Object.clone:

> Error: method clone in class Object cannot be accessed in Option[JavaAPI] 
>   Access to protected method clone not permitted because prefix type
>   Option[JavaAPI] does not conform to class D in package a.b.c where the access
>   take place

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try putting `()` at the end of the call to `clone`?

Comment: And it isn't because the interface is package protected? (No access modifier in Scala means public but package protected in Java)

Comment: JavaAPI is public. And putting () at the end of clone didn't make any difference.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear (added public modifier to Java interface and matched class names in error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all see [Object#clone() signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--)

```java
protected Object clone()
                throws CloneNotSupportedException
```

You want to override this method.

In your example now you have two methods:

```java
protected Object clone()
                    throws CloneNotSupportedException
```

```java
public JustSomeAPISpecificType clone()
```

See:

JustSomeAPISpecificType.java

```
public enum JustSomeAPISpecificType{
INSTANCE
}
```

Factory.java

```
public class Factory {

        public static class JavaApiImpl implements JavaAPI{

                public JustSomeAPISpecificType clone(){
                        return JustSomeAPISpecificType.INSTANCE;
                }
        }

        public static JavaAPI getAPI(){
                return new JavaApiImpl();
        }
}
```

Now add your files to `src/main/java` and run `sbt console` from root:

```scala
scala> val api = Factory.getAPI
api: JavaAPI = Factory$JavaApiImpl@4243eb68

scala> api.getClass.getMethods.filter(m => m.getName.startsWith("clone")).mkString("\n")
res0: String = 
public JustSomeAPISpecificType Factory$JavaApiImpl.clone()
public java.lang.Object Factory$JavaApiImpl.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException
```

**Update**
If you cast - you will see the method clone (if the factory is public).

```
scala> api.asInstanceOf[Factory.JavaApiImpl].clone
res4: JustSomeAPISpecificType = INSTANCE
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's the API of a given Java library that provides this clone method. How can I convince the Scala compiler to use JavaAPI.clone() now?

Comment: Try the reflection api. But you want to break the rules. See [clone contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) `x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()`.

Comment: Okay, thank you, by using reflection I'm able to call clone() of the Java API, although I was hoping for a more elegant solution... By the way, I'm aware of the clone contract and don't want to break it. It's just the Java library I'm using.

Comment: This is bug is scala. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/WaMDZqm8CC0 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15861169/651140

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the Java factory is not public. I can live with the reflection approach for now. But note that the bug you mentioned was fixed in Scala 2.7.2 according to the bug tracker and I'm using 2.10.3.

Comment: It was solved - and again occurred. It is regression. Your code is a good test.

Comment: I use reflection for now until this bug is fixed and mark this as resolved.