# Scala error "value map is not a member of Double"

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming

Explanation: I accepted [gzm0's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149944/gzm0) answer because it rocked!

@Eduardo did come in with a comment suggesting:

```
(for(i <- 10..20; j=runTest(i)) yield i -> j).toMap
```

which also lets me run build, he just never posted an answer and @gzm0 answer was conceptually AWESOME so I accepted it.

[Once I get this other issue figured out relating to "can't call constructor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983987/scala-constructor-stopwatch-cannot-be-accessed-in-class-main) I will be able to test these out by actually running the program LOL

Question: I have an error in this expression, specifically how to fix it but more generally what am I missing about FP or Scala to make this mistake?

```
timingsMap = for (i <- powersList; j <- runTest(i)) yield i -> j
```

I am Writing my first Gradle/Scala project for a Analysis of Algorithms assignment. Scala is not part of the assignment so I am not using a homework tag. Except for my work with Spark in Java, I am brand new to Functional Programming I am sure that's the problem.

Here's a snippet, [the full .scala file is on GitHub](https://github.com/jimlohse/RedBlackTree4150/blob/master/src/main/scala/Main.scala), is that OK or I will post the full program here if I get flailed :)

```
val powersList = List(10 to 20)

// create a map to keep track of power of two and resulting timings
var timingsMap: Map[Integer, Double] = Map()

// call the runTest function once for each power of two we want, from powersList,
// assign timingsMap the power of 2 value and results of runTest for that tree size
timingsMap = for (i <- powersList; j <- runTest(i)) yield i -> j
```

The error is:
    /home/jim/workspace/Scala/RedBlackTree4150/src/main/scala/Main.scala:36: value map is not a member of Double
      timingsMap = for (i <- powersList; j <- runTest(i)) yield i -> j

What I **think** I am doing in that `timingsMap = ...` line is get all the elements of `powersList` mapped onto `i` for each iteration of the loop, and the return value for `runTest(i)` mapped onto `j` for each iteration, and then taking all those pairs and putting them into `timingsMap`. Is it the way I am trying to use `i` in the loop to `call runTest(i)` that causes the problem?

runTest looks like this:

```
def runTest(powerOfTwo: Range): Double = {

    // create the tree here
    var tree = new TreeMap[Int, Double]

    // we only care to create a tree with integer keys, not what the value is
    for (x <- powerOfTwo) {
      // set next entry in map to key, random number
      tree += (x -> math.random)
    }

    stopWatchInst.start()

    // now go through and look up all the values in the tree,
    for (x <- powerOfTwo) {
      // get the value, don't take the time/overhead to store it in a var, as we don't need it
      tree.get(x)
    }

    // stop watch check time report and return time
    stopWatchInst.stop()
    val totalTime = stopWatchInst.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    loggerInst.info("run for 2 to the power of " + powerOfTwo + " took " + totalTime + " ms")
    return totalTime
  }
```

---

Note: I've had a suggestions to change the `j <-` to `=` in `j <-` in this line: timingsMap = for (i <- powersList; j <- runTest(i)) yield i -> j

Another suggestion didn't like using yield at all and suggested replacing with (10 to 20).map...

**The strange part is the existing code does not show an error in the IntelliJ editor, only breaks when I run it. The suggestions all give type mismatch errors in the IDE. I am really trying to figure out conceptually** what I am doing wrong, thanks for any help! (and of course I need to get it to work!)

---

After trying gzm0 answer I am getting down the same road ... my code as presented doesn't show any type mismatches until I use `gradle run` ... whereas when I make the suggested changes it starts to give me errors right in the IDE ... but keep em coming! Here's the latest error based on gzm0s answer:

```
/home/jim/workspace/Scala/RedBlackTree4150/src/main/scala/Main.scala:37: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive, Double)]
 required: Map[Integer,Double]
  timingsMap = for (i <- powersList) yield i -> runTest(i)
```

Comment: Took the parens off class `RedBlackTree4150()` made no difference I can see ... I have access through Safari Books to Learning Scala and Wampler's Programming Scala so if there's a good reference in there please use chapter/section titles not page numbers thanks :)

Comment: There was an answer posted but it was turning into a long discussion and he didn't want to go to chat, I wish that user had not deleted the answer! They were suggesting I use something like (10 to 20).map but we got into a lot of type mismatches. I think what I am doing with `for ... yield` is the same as map, under the hood. Is there a reason to avoid `for ... yield`? That user didn't like it.

Comment: use `j = runTest(i)` with an `=` and not `<-`. The `<-` sign is for when you have collections. `runTest` just returns a `Double` value

Comment: Very helpful, got me to look at the Scala spec to learn more, but I still get a type mismatch `/home/jim/workspace/Scala/RedBlackTree4150/src/main/scala/Main.scala:36: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive, Double)]
 required: Map[Integer,Double]
  timingsMap = for (i <- powersList; j = runTest(i)) yield i -> j`

Comment: The timingsMap is supposed to be a group of tuples with (power of 2 tested, an integer; time it took to run, a double) ... I will add a note to the end of my question

Comment: Use `val powersList = 10 to 20`. `10 to 20` gives you a range, and the `<-` will extract from that, integer by integer. There is no need to wrap it inside a List.

Comment: I forget now why I made it a list ... now runTest doesn't have the right signature to make this work ... rather than getting into a long discussion here maybe post an answer and we can comment there? ... I see gzm0 just posted an answer let me check that out

Comment: OK. I think, once you reach that point, you can fix it by wrapping the whole for/yield expression in parenthesis and calling `.toMap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
for (i <- powersList)
  yield i -> runTest(i)
```

The result of `runTest` is not a list, therefore you can't give it to the `for` statement. The reason that you get a bit of a strange error message, is due to how your `for` is desugared:

```
for (i <- powersList; j <- runTest(i)) yield i -> j

// turns into

powersList.flatMap { i => runTest(i).map { j => i -> j } }
```

However, the result of `runTest(i)` is a `Double`, which doesn't have a `map` method. So looking at the desugaring, the error message actually makes sense.

Note that my point about `runTest`'s result not being a list is not really correct: Anything that has a `map` method that will allow the above statement (i.e. taking some kind of lambda) will do. However, this is beyond the scope of this answer.

We now have successfully created a list of tuples (since `powersList` is a `List`, the result of the `for` loop is a `List` as well). However, we want a `Map`. Luckily, you can call `toMap` on `List`s that contain tuples to convert them into a `Map`:

```
val tups = for (i <- powersList) yield i -> runTest(i)
timingsMap = tups.toMap
```

A note aside: If you really want to keep the `j` inside the `for`-loop, you can use the equals sign instead of the left arrow:

```
for (i <- powersList; j = runTest(i)) yield i -> j
```

This will turn into:

```
powersList.map { i =>
  val j = runTest(i)
  i -> j
}
```

Which is what you want.

Comment: I put `timingsMap = for (i <- powersList) yield i -> runTest(i)` and get this error: `/home/jim/workspace/Scala/RedBlackTree4150/src/main/scala/Main.scala:37: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive, Double)]
 required: Map[Integer,Double]
  timingsMap = for (i <- powersList) yield i -> runTest(i)` which I will edit into my question for readability

Comment: @ChrisMartin I know. Added more explanation. It still is not clear enough, I'll improve.

Comment: Let me read your revised answer, I added the error to the end of my answer ... really appreciate everyone's suggestions but they start me down a path of type mismatches ... which is OK if it lead somewhere :) .... AHHHH just read your extended answer VERY COOL THANKS let me try that, that's the explanation I have been waiting for!

Comment: Isn't there still an error? In my answer I assign a `Map[Range, Double]` to a `Map[Integer, Double]`. Do you want the map to contain range -> time or point -> time mappings?

Comment: ding ding ding!!! (the good ding) we have a winner. Very complete answer, that totally explains why I was not seeing an error in the IDE, only on run. Thanks for the super-explanation, it now runs and only has the two errors in another question I asked. You da man! The other question BTW is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983987/scala-constructor-stopwatch-cannot-be-accessed-in-class-main which I think is really the easy one so I am surprise no one has jumped on it yet thanks again!!!!

Comment: on your last comment, I think you have given me the tools I need, I want the timingsMap to have tuples of (power of 2 tests, time it took to run). Once I get the other linked question sorted out I can start actually running this thing