# Scala "constructor DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy in class DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy cannot be accessed in object CassandraConnector"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am a scala newbie and really need help with an issue I've been experiencing with some code. I have set up the following code to create cassandra connections:

```
package some.package

import java.net.InetAddress
import java.util

import com.datastax.driver.core._
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.{DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy, TokenAwarePolicy}

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object CassandraConnector {

  def getCluster(contactPointIpString: String, preferred_dc: String): Cluster = {

    val contactPointIpStrings = contactPointIpString.split(",").toList

    val contactPointIpList = contactPointIpStrings.flatMap { ipAddress: String => InetAddress.getAllByName(ipAddress) }
    println(s"Building Cluster w/ Contact Points: $contactPointIpList")

    Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoints(contactPointIpList)
      .withClusterName("multi_dc_user_data")
      .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(preferred_dc)))
      .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE))
      .build()
  }

}
```

While building the project in IntelliJ, the following error happens:

```
constructor DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy in class DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy cannot be accessed in object CassandraConnector
      .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(preferred_dc)))
```

Found something similar to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983987/scala-constructor-stopwatch-cannot-be-accessed-in-class-main), and tried to change my code to the following:

```
val dcAwareRoundRobinPolicyBuilder = new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder
val dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy = dcAwareRoundRobinPolicyBuilder.withLocalDc(preferred_dc)

Cluster.builder()
  .addContactPoints(contactPointIpList)
  .withClusterName("multi_dc_user_data")
  .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(dcAwareRoundRobinPolicy.build()))
  .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE))
  .build()
```

This resolved the issue and now the build finishes successfully but I am not so sure if what I've done is necessarily correct, so I'd really appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

`DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy` uses the Builder Pattern to decouple the public API for instance creation from the particular implementation of the constructors for the instances.  This is accomplished by not exposing a public constructor and instead only allowing `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder` to construct instances of `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy`.

You're using it as it's intended (assuming that you're passing options which match what you're expecting).